# How to execute script only after chef updates all nodes?

Tags: chef

I want to make a recipe that deploys our software update executable to all servers and then publishes new version info to database. How to make script that makes database request only after all nodes with given role deployed new package version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the recipe that deploys the executable, I would consider storing the new software version in a node attribute after the executable has been deployed.  Then, in a separate recipe, run a search across those nodes and verify that all of the results contain only the new software version, i.e.:

```
if search(:node, 'roles:role_for_your_app_servers').reject do |n|
  n['software']['version'] != target_version
end.empty?

  do_database_update

end
```

For this to work you will want to first make sure that all of your nodes include the software version attribute before adding this function.